# Graph API naming issue when trying to set SharePoint meta data fields

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the graph api (in C#) to be able to set meta data fields for documents in my SharePoint.
To achieve this, I'm using the code below

```
public async Task SetMetaData(SharePointFile file, params MetaDataField[] fields)
{
    FieldValueSet fieldValueSet = new()
    {
        AdditionalData = fields.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value)
    };
    
    await _graphClient.Drives[file.Library.Id].Items[file.Id].ListItem.Fields
        .Request()
        .UpdateAsync(fieldValueSet);
}
```

This works fine most of the time, but I noticed two problems:

First, once I rename a field and try to set the value from the new name it doesn't recognize that field anymore. Looking at the library settings I noticed that the URL doesn't "update" but rather stays. With this, I tried working with the old name and it still works fine. When trying to fetch meta data it still retains the old name. Is there some way to get the new name? Especially so it can be tracked to the old one?

Second, if the field does have ":" in its name, the request will execute "successfully" but the value of the field is not changed. I know that things like locations are split in multiple field in the form of "TestLocation" -> "TestLocation:Country"/"TestLocation:Position" etc. Does this conflict with this somehow? And how do you surpass this?

(I worked with a simple text field in this case)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [internal name](https://sharepointstuff.com/2022/02/09/find-internal-column-name/) of the field cannot be modified, you only modified the display name of the field in the UI.

As a workaround, you have to create another column with the name you would like to give, copy the data and then delete the old column. Refer to [similar question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/is-there-a-way-to-edit-the-internal-name-of-a-list/9edc17da-4ff0-4f1a-95b4-35c99e1d0a94).

Also, if you want to update the field value then you can refer to the following code snippet:

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(requestAdapter);

var requestBody = new FieldValueSet
{
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {
            "Color" , "Fuchsia"
        },
        {
            "Quantity" , 934
        },
    },
};
var result = await graphClient.Sites["{site-id}"].Lists["{list-id}"].Items["{listItem-id}"].Fields.PatchAsync(requestBody);
```